# How to fix python popup message "The python command requires the command line developer tools"?

Tags: terminal, command-line, python

On MacOS Ventura 13.4 I just wanted to create a small python 3.9.6 code that is using `subprocess.Popen`, and when I started it there was a popup saying "The python command requires the command line developer tools"

[image]

What does this mean? Why do I have to install something now? How much GB of diskspace will that use? Can I use python `subprocess.Popen` without installing something? What is happening? Why? How to fix this problem?

Python path: `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Are you using the Python from /usr/bin, or something you installed on your own?

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: You need to add to your question that you have a version of python installed. But it's pretty clear that something is calling the system python at /usr/bin/python3, which isn't installed. Ideally, we'd need to see the line of code.

Comment: I noted I have python 3.9.6 installed. And what do you mean by python is not installed? You are saying python is not installed although I use python like the whole day?

Comment: APPLE's python is not installed. The version of python that you have installed has a different filepath, e.g. not /usr/bin/python3.

Comment: The python I have installed has path `/usr/bin/python3`. As I mentioned above

Comment: You can't overwrite an existing Apple system file. If you type `/usr/bin/python3` in Terminal, what happens? (E.g. not just `python3`)

Comment: That starts the python interpreter. ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146729/discussion-between-alex-and-benwiggy).